# Can not resize disk image file .dmg

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I've found that OS X supports .img files which might be resized after it was created. Interesting thing is I can not resize more than 1 time :) is it real limitation or I'm doing something wrong ?

I've made an image file via Disk Utility, selected image format: sparse. And was able write on it up to the selected size, then I was able to increase it's size once (with Disk Utility), put files up to capacity and THEN I can't resize it anymore [image]

Comment: @grgarsiden I checked it, but Console.app keeps silent :(

Comment: Same problem. Tried to use hdiutil resize also give silent result.

Comment: I also get this.  It is not a very informative error dialog.

Comment: If it's a spareseimage, it's not using up the space that makes up it's capacity, until you actually copy files to it. This when you make a sparseimage, you really can make it gigantic. Make it 100GB or 1000GB. It will still take up no space until you load it up.

Comment: You say .img in first line. Did you mean .dmg?

Answer (score 33):

I have the same error message.

This worked for me in Terminal (thanks to [Ray's Weblog](https://ep1curus.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/resize-a-sparse-bundle-image-using-terminal/)):

```
hdiutil resize -size 1g ~/Documents/MyDiskImage.dmg
```

Comment: Funny that in my case I specified `-size 150g` but it resized to 160GB ‍♂️. However it worked, thank you! *+1*

Comment: This also works on read/write disk image, thank you.

Comment: When I typed hdiutil resize -size 35g ~/Volumes/Transcend\ SD\ Card/Backup.dmg, the Terminal said that “No such file or directory”. Did I type it wrong somehow?

Comment: @Kamafeather — In `150g`, the `g` represents 1024^3, not 1000^3, so `150g` works out to approximately 161*1000^3 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, it's always hard to figure out what unit each different utility uses. Some use Gigabits, others Gigabytes, and it's not clear what a `g` or `G` are meant to represent.